# Turn off Rocket Loader for Google DoubleClick

Tags: php, jquery, cloudflare

How can I turn off RocketLoader for google DoubleClick Ads ?

RocketLoader is affecting on GeoLocation and DoubleClick Ads is not working properly based on Geo Location because Rocket Loader is doing the code async.

```
<script type='text/rocketscript'>
        googletag.defineSlot('/7229/test/general', [1, 1], 'div-gpt-ad-1362035459309-0').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.defineSlot('/7229/test/general', [728, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-136209309-1').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.defineSlot('/7229/test/general', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-136209309-2').addService(googletag.pubads());
        googletag.defineSlot('/7229/test/general', [970, 90], 'div-gpt-ad-136209309-3').addService(googletag.pubads());

        googletag.defineOutOfPageSlot('/7229/test/general', 'div-gpt-ad-136209309-0-oop').addService(googletag.pubads());

        googletag.pubads().enableSyncRendering();
        googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
        googletag.enableServices();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169436--How-can-I-have-Rocket-Loader-ignore-my-script-s-in-Automatic-Mode-

Note: That doesn't always work. It would probably be best if you open a support ticket so we can see why it is breaking.